# I try to create a new column separating a column into two and then changing the new one with transmute function, but the r throws an error

Tags: r

I want to separate one column into two and then change the new column so that the last character is dropped, but I get an error. Here is the code:

```
imdb_ratings <- imdb_ratings %>%   select(title, Animation, imdbRating, ratingCount, 
                                      nrOfNewsArticles) %>% 
                               filter(Animation == 1, !str_detect(title, "'\'$")) %>% 
                               separate(col = title, into = c("title", "year"),  
                                        sep = "\\(") %>%
                               transmute(year = substr(year, start = 1, nchar(year)-1))
```

Here is the error: `Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with`NA`in 1051 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...].`

I tried to use mutate, mutate_at functions as well, but they don't work. The year column is defined as character.

And if I delete the transmute function it still gives me an error:

```
imdb_ratings <- imdb_ratings %>%   select(title, Animation, imdbRating, ratingCount, 
                                          nrOfNewsArticles) %>% 
                                   filter(Animation == 1, !str_detect(title, "'\'$")) %>% 
                                   separate(col = title, into = c("title", "year"),  
                                            sep = "\\(")
```

Error: `This tidyselect interface doesn't support predicates yet.`

Comment: In your code you have `transmutate()` where it should be `transmute()`

Comment: @qdread Even if I delete the transmute option it gives me the same error. When I changed it to transmute, it made every symbol in the column "year" equal to NA.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).